# Check date format is DD-MMM-YYYY

Tags: python, pyspark

I have below pyspark dataframe for example. I want to validate in the dataframe if the value is in 'dd-mmm-yyyy'format and show pass has the status or else show status has fail.

[image]

I tried with the below code but it fails with the error to_date is not defined. Any inputs on getting this pass and fail status

`df.select(c,F.when(to_date(tsrcreateddate, 'dd-mmm-yyyy') ,"pass").otherwise("fail").alias("Check"))`

Comment: are you sure the function to_date is correct? Or is is the Pandas function pd.to_datetime()? You could check: import pandas as pd, 
value = pd.to_datetime('30-05-2021', format='%d-%m-%Y', errors='ignore')

Comment: yes to_date is correct. I was missing the F.to_date. getting new error now:  : WHEN expressions in CaseWhen should all be boolean type, but the 1th when expression's type is to_date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find solution using below code.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

# Create SparkSession

data=[["1","2020-02-01"],["2","2019-03-01"],["3","2021-03-01"],["4",""],["5","2021-21-01"],["6","1900-01-01"]]
df=spark.createDataFrame(data,["id","input"])
df.show()

c='input'
df1= df.select(c,F.when(F.col(c).rlike("^(19|20)\d\d[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$") ,"pass").otherwise("fail").alias("Check"))
df1.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

See if the code below does what you want:

```
import datetime

date_string = '30-5-2021'
format = '%d-%m-%Y'

try:
  datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, format)
  print(date_string + " is a date in with correct format.")
except ValueError:
  print(date_string + " does not have correct format")
```